# Vim -- Double Inclusion Guard

Tags: vim

Id'd like to be able to repeatedly insource my `~/.vimrc.local` file (I'm using the `sp13-vim` distro), but I get error messages in the part of that file when I have `Bundle/UnBundle` statements. How can I prevent that part to be double executed.

That is, how do I write the following in Vimscript?:

```
if guard_global_not_defined
   define_guard_global
   do stuff
endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canonical structure is

```
if !exists('g:didBundle')
    let g:didBundle = 1
    Bundle ...
    ...
endif
```

As bundles are globally scoped, the `g:` prefix makes it a global guard. You can do the same with other scopes (e.g. `b:` for buffer-local stuff).

Answer (score 2):

The local_vimrc files I'm using have the following kind of include guards: https://github.com/LucHermitte/Rasende/blob/master/_vimrc_local.vim

The latest [templates](https://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/mu-template/trunk/after/template/vim/internals) I'm using are a little bit different (they are meant to support projects having [global definitions](https://github.com/LucHermitte/Rasende/blob/master/_vimrc_local_global_defs.vim) that need to be set before the local settings (like a project name, where to find sources, build configurations and their related build directories), and local tunings).

When expanded, the result look like this (you certainly don't need everything):

```
let s:k_version = 42
" Always loaded {{{1
" Buffer-local Definitions {{{1
" Avoid local reinclusion {{{2
if &cp || (exists("b:loaded_tests_lh_vimrc_local")
      \ && (b:loaded_tests_lh_vimrc_local >= s:k_version)
      \ && !exists('g:force_reload_tests_lh_vimrc_local'))
  finish
endif
let b:loaded_tests_lh_vimrc_local = s:k_version
let s:cpo_save=&cpo
set cpo&vim

" ======================[ Project config {{{2
if ! (exists("g:loaded_tests_lh_vimrc_local")
      \ && (g:loaded_tests_lh_vimrc_local >= s:k_version)
      \ && !exists('g:force_reload_tests_lh_vimrc_local'))
  source <sfile>:p:h/_vimrc_local_global_defs.vim
endif


" ======================[ Local settings {{{2
.... <- here go your local settings

"--------------------------------------------------------------------
" Global Definitions {{{1
" Avoid global reinclusion {{{2
if &cp ||  (exists("g:loaded_tests_lh_vimrc_local")
      \ && (g:loaded_tests_lh_vimrc_local >= s:k_version)
      \ && !exists('g:force_reload_tests_lh_vimrc_local'))
  finish
endif
let g:loaded_tests_lh_vimrc_local = s:k_version

" ======================[ Functions {{{2
.... <- here go some more global stuff like functions

" }}}1
"--------------------------------------------------------------------
let &cpo=s:cpo_save
"====================================================================
" vim600: set fdm=marker:
```

PS: I found quite odd that you have a local_vimrc at your very $HOME directory. They are meant to be at the root of project trees. And moreover they shall not be loaded by a plugin manager but by a [local-vimrc](https://github.com/LucHermitte/local_vimrc) plugin.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  TL;DR: `if !exists("g:my_var") ... let g:my_var=true ... endif`

Comment: Given the name of your script, the variable is more likely `b:my_var`.